# Call ReferenceClass methods in data.table's :=

Tags: r, data.table, reference-class

I am having problems to call methods of `ReferenceClass` objects and assign the return values directly by reference to a `data.table` column (`data.table` version 1.9.3, R version 3.1) as this minimal example shows:

```
RF <- setRefClass(
  Class = "RF",
  methods = list(
    get = function() { "/foo/bar" }
  )
)
rf <- RF$new()

mdt <- data.table( x= c("a", "b"), y = 1:2 )
mdt[ , z := rf$get() ] # gives warning

> mdt$z
[[1]]
`$`

[[2]]
rf
```

`mdt[ , rf$get() ]` works as expected, while `mdt[ , list( z = rf$get()) ][ , z]` gives a weird result as well and `mdt[ , unlist(list( z = rf$get())) ]` gives an error.

I do not need a solution like *evaluate `rf$get()` outside `mdt` and then assign the result*. I'd rather like to understand what is going on here, since I am making vast use of `data.tables` and `ReferenceClasses` and would like to use them properly together.

Comment: this has nothing to do with `ReferenceClass` and is a bug in `construct`/`deconstruct_and_eval` internal functions - please submit a bug report - any construct of form `dt[, a := b$c()]` will fail

Comment: @eddi so if I got this right the new home of `data.table` and accordingly tracking the bugs is github and not r-forge any longer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for filing the issue. This has been now fixed [in 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/022272f1e8d3df2ad9874796dc963d0dd6a250dd). From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> `j`-expressions in `DT[, col := x$y()]` (or) `DT[, col := x[[1]]()]` are now (re)constructed properly. Thanks to @ihaddad-md for reporting. Closes [#774](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/774).

Your code gives the result:

```
#    x y        z
# 1: a 1 /foo/bar
# 2: b 2 /foo/bar
```

without any warnings.